# how to check if an image clicked in php

Tags: php, query-string

I have little cycle. This take some image to the screen. Every image have an id which i stored in $id variable.

When user click on an image they get a popup window. Now im use query string. When user click, get a popup with id from query string.

But this is not a good way, 'coz if user reload the page, with the query string..they get the popup every time.

I need the $id when show the popup. How can i do this without querystring? How can i check if click on image and which image clicked on?

```
for j=1 .....{
...
..

 for i=1....... {
  $id=array[j,i];

   echo "<a href=test.php><img style='z-index:$z; position:absolute; left: $lf; top: $tf;' src='images/$src' width='$width' height='$heigth' title='$title' /></a>";


 }
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what your asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to trigger the popup when the user clicks on the image. This way, nothing is sent back to the server, and there is no query string.

I don't see where you print the id for each picture to the page, but because it is psuedocode, I'll assume it works. Using javascript would look something like this:

```
for j=1 .....{
  ...
  ..

 for i=1....... {
  $id=array[j,i];

   echo "<a href='javascript:alert(\"$id)\"'><img style='z-index:$z; position:absolute; left: $lf; top: $tf;' src='images/$src' width='$width' height='$heigth' title='$title' /></a>";

 }
}
```

Clicking on the image would then generate a popup with the id of the image, and no information would be sent to the server.

Comment: ok. with this way i can check which image clicked on. but if Js disabled..other methode?

Comment: Regarding disabled JS, you have to ask yourself if your target audience is likely to have JS disabled, and if it's worth providing a fallback method.

Answer (score 0):

you can put one function that will be incremented counter when someone click on the image. and that counter will be increment by 1 and u can also set it into database..

Try this..
thanks.

Comment: Glad you two are speaking the same language.